# $SU(2)$ Invariant Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, group-theory, representation-theory, electroweak, charge-conjugation

Consider two arbitrary scalar multiplets $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ invariant under $SU(2)\times U(1)$. When writing the potential for this model, in addition to usual terms like $\Phi^\dagger \Phi + (\Phi^\dagger \Phi)^2$, I often see in the literature, less usual terms like:
$$\Phi^\dagger T^a \Phi \ \Psi^\dagger t^a \Psi + \Phi^{c\dagger} T^a \Phi \ \Psi^\dagger t^a \Psi^c $$
where $T^a$ and $t^a$ are SU(2) generators in different representations, and charge conjugate representation is defined as $\Phi^c \equiv C \Phi^*$, with $C$ being the anti-symmetric charge conjugation matrix (like $\epsilon$ matrix in 2-dimensional representation).

See for an example eqn (1) in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3656).

I am wondering why the above terms are invariant under an $SU(2)$ transformation?

Any helps or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the $C$ matrix is that if $\Phi$ transforms like $\Phi\rightarrow U\Phi$, where $U$ is some representation of SU(2), then also $\Phi^c\rightarrow U\Phi^c$. You can work it out yourself using the $\epsilon$ matrix for the case of the fundamental representation.

Now taking the complex conjugate we have $\Phi^\dagger\rightarrow \Phi^\dagger U^{-1}$ (similarly for $\Phi^c$), and so
$$\Phi^\dagger \tau^a \Phi\rightarrow \Phi^\dagger\left( U^{-1}\tau^a U\right)\Phi=R(U)^a_{\,b}\Phi^\dagger\tau^b\Phi$$
where $R(U)$ is the adjoint representation of SU(2).

So the terms as you wrote them are not $SU(2)$ invariant, they are in the adjoint representation. But if you look in the paper they are contracted with another factor in the adjoint representation (with index $a$), and so the entire term with both factors is invariant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please a bit elaborate on why $U^{-1} t^a U=R(U)^a_b \ t^b$.

Answer (score 1):

They are suppressing the SU(2) indices. If this is your first pass you have every right to be confused. I will be very explicit with my indices so you can see the underlying structure.

**Theorem:** The product of two representations of $\phi, \psi$ of SU(2) is invariant iff their indices are contracted with an invariant tensor (of the same representation) of SU(2).

That's a bit of a mouthful, but the following should clarify. There are two invariant tensors of the **2** rep of $SU(2)$ (1) $\epsilon_{ab}$ and (2) $\delta_{\bar{a} b}$. The bar denotes an index that transforms under the complex conjugate representation.

Now, let's write out your two vectors $\Phi$ , and $\Phi^\dagger$ explicitly with indices. The would look like

$$ \Phi \sim \Phi_a \qquad \Phi^\dagger \sim \Phi^\dagger_\bar{a}$$

**Here is the issue I have with the question**: As the question is phrased, it is simply not true in general. As mentioned in the first paragraph under the "theorem", the only two invariant contractions of two SU(2) doublets are

$$ \Phi^\dagger_\bar{a} \delta_{\bar{a} b} \Phi_b \sim \Phi^\dagger \Phi$$

and

$$ \Phi_a\Phi_b \epsilon_{ab} \sim \Phi \Phi$$.

The latter is referred to as the singlet representation, where on the right I have written the "suppressed index" notation of each contraction.

**Possible resolution**: My *guess* is that the paper is assuming that $\Phi$ transforms in the **Adjoint** representation of SU(2) (also referred to as the **3**). If this is the case, then **indeed** the contraction between the **3** and another **3** given by

$$ \Phi^\dagger_{i} T^a_{ij} \Phi_j$$

where $T^a$ is a generator of the **fundamental** of SU(2), **is** indeed an invariant of the adjoint representation if SU(2). If you look at the gauge-covariant derivative of QCD this is exactly the same thing (except with SU(3)).

**Conclusion**: The two different invariants you are talking about are for two **different** representations of SU(2). Indeed, almost whenever you see $\Phi^\dagger T^a \Phi$ they are almost always talking about the adjoint of SU(3) (the **8** of SU(3)) and not the **3** of SU(2). But the point is that the two invariants you wrote correspond to two **different** representations of SU(2) (the fundamental and the adjoint) and so can never appear in the same lagrangian (unless you furnish your reps with *both* indices), you will only see them in different theories.